# How to get external mic working through DSLR camera on Zoom on Mac?

Tags: video, audio, dslr, microphone

I have tried taking the advice and [plugging my mic into my camera](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/34114/noticeable-video-delay-when-connecting-to-laptop-and-dslr-external-mic/34128#34128), but it is now not working, for the question [Noticeable video delay when connecting to laptop and DSLR + external mic](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/34114/noticeable-video-delay-when-connecting-to-laptop-and-dslr-external-mic). Now I am not getting any sound signal coming in from Zoom. How do I wire things up correctly?

- I have my Rode mic wired to the Rode USB audio interface.
- I have that plugged into my camera with [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0928WL1Q8).
- I have the camera using a mini HDMI to HDMI, plugged into an HDMI video capture device.
- The video capture device is plugged into a USB hub.
- The USB hub is plugged into my M1 MacBook Pro laptop.

How do I get the audio to play so it (hopefully) syncs with the video? What am I plugging in wrong and/or doing incorrectly? Should I even be using the USB Audio Interface at all if I have that 3.5mm plug to go straight into the camera? Should I be having some sort of Mic-to-camera direct adapter or something? What should be done to get this system to work? Are things plugged into the right places on the camera and such?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's multiple possible points of failure here - the splitter cable might be faulty, settings on the camera or mac might be incorrect, there might be no audio signal coming through your HDMI, etc. It will need narrowing down with further testing to determine where the audio is being lost.

Do you have a basic 1/8" male to male cable that you can take audio output from another device to test the camera audio with? i.e. plug it into a headphone jack on a phone or similar device, and see if that audio is coming through on camera? Does the camera have any kind of monitoring facility, either on screen showing levels, or through headphones? I would also try making a recording on camera, and see if that has audio with it - perhaps the camera is getting the audio fine, but it is not passing through to the mac via the HDMI interface.

Next check your HDMI interface. If you plug the camera HDMI out into a TV, do you get the sound through there? If you plug another HDMI device into the laptop, is there any sound on the capture? Under "System Preferences" / "Sound" on the mac, what is being shown as the input device? Is the volume correctly set, and is the monitoring showing active audio from the microphone?